# Group by de registros por data e id de usuario

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Boa tarde!

Tenho uma tabela como essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso realizar um SELECT que conte quantos registros tenho por mes e ano, mas agrupando ao mesmo tempo os registros "repetidos"...(Registros repetidos nesse caso são os registro como o de id 1, 2 e 3 que tem o mesmo id de usuario e um horario proximo de no maximo 30 segundos, como esses 3 registros).

Consegui realizar um SELECT, mas não consigo remover esses repetidos.

```
SELECT count(id), YEAR(data_hora), MONTH(data_hora) FROM teste GROUP BY MONTH(data_hora), YEAR(data_hora)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso, os registros do mes 3 de 2021, deveriam ser agrupados e ao inves de mostrar 3 registros, deveria ser apenas um...

Espero que eu tenha conseguido explicar, aceito sugestões para melhorar minha pergunta!

Ah, estou utilizando mariaDB 10.4.10

Answer (score 2):

Sua query tem um problema:

Ao fazer o group por mes/ano apenas, vai ter a variação por id_user, por isso não vai agrupar aquele 3 como 1. Ou seja, para um mesmo mes/ano, vai trazer mais de um.

Se agrupar por id_user, ainda assim vai trazer mais de um, pois são id_user diferentes.

Uma solução é, primeiro selecionar os registros não repetidos por id_user (aqui vamos usar um `DISTINCT` para isso), juntamente com mes/ano, sem usar o id, pois ele é diferente para cada registro e vai estragar o group, assim:

```
SELECT distinct(id_user) id_user,
       YEAR(data_hora) ano, 
       MONTH(data_hora) mes 
  FROM teste;
```

Isso vai retornar:

```
id_user ano     mes
2       2021    3
5       2021    1
6       2021    12
8       2021    2
```

Agora que temos um único registro por id_usuario/mes/ano, podemos contar e fazer o `group by`:

```
SELECT COUNT(id_user),
       ano,
       mes
 FROM
(SELECT distinct(id_user) id_user,
       YEAR(data_hora) ano, 
       MONTH(data_hora) mes 
  FROM teste) as sub
GROUP BY mes, ano;
```

Pode ver funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ca8a/8

Para demonstrar um caso que não tem no seu exemplo, adicionei outro usuário no mesmo mes/ano, que vai contar com 2 nesse caso.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo! Otima resposta, Ricardo. Entretanto, ainda tenho um problema. Seu SQL "agrupa" o mesmo id_user se ele ocorrer no mesmo mês, e na verdade, eu só posso que eles sejam agrupados, quando a diferença entre seus horario for de 30 segundos. Exemplo: se eu tiver 3 registros de um user id 2, no dia 15, mas os data_hora deles são diferentes, 12/3/2021 10:00:00, 12/3/2021 10:00:05, 12/3/2021 09:00:00, nesse caso, dois devem ser agrupados e outro não.

Comment: olha 30 segundos vai dar muito trabalho, precisa de calculos... se for uma unidade interira, por exemplo dias, horas ou minutos, pode adicionar na primeira query, assim como year e month,e vai funcionar. Já 30 segundos talvez precise de uma terceira query. Pode tentar converter para timestamp tb e ver quanto é o valor de 30s e arredondar, mas como disse, precisa de cálculo

Comment: Boa ideia, vou tentar com 1 minuto. Muito obrigado, Ricado.